# Dose not change html text box input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm selecting a file from file explorer by using `<input type="file">` which has css property `display:none` but I click on a `<a>` tag which will trigger the `<input type="file">`. Bellow my HTML and JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

    <script>
            function BrowseFile() {
                $('.attachmentlabel').val('spooky');
                $('#file-01').click();

                var filePath = $('#file-01').val().split('\\'),
                    fileName = filePath[filePath.length - 1];

                if (fileName !== '' && fileName !== undefined) {
                    $('.attachmentlabel').val(fileName);
                }
            }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" class="hidden-attachment" id='file-01'> @*the hidden field*@
    <input type="text" name="Attachment" class="attachmentlabel"> @*here I want to show the file name*@
     <a  class="btn attachmnentbtn browse" onclick="BrowseFile()">Browse</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I'm trying to do is if I click on `<a>` it will call `BrowseFile()` and this method will trigger click event on `<input type="file" class="hidden-attachment">`

I tried the above code but this is not changing the text content of `<input type='text'>`. How can I fix this and what is the reason for this

Comment: setting display: none actually affects click event bubbling. set opactiy:0 instead

Comment: It working fine for me check this http://jsfiddle.net/q76zfLuq/1/

Comment: @Sadikhasan: I didn't see it displaying file name after I select the file. The file name supposed to replace "spooky"

Comment: Check updated demo link http://jsfiddle.net/q76zfLuq/3/

Comment: Onchange will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#file-01").change(function () {
          $('.attachmentlabel').val($(this).val())
     });
});
```

Simply you can handle change event of your file control, and update the same in textbox.

**Check bellow code**

```js
var repassword = "hello";
var password = "hello";

repassword = "hello1";
password = "hello";


function BrowseFile() {
                $('.attachmentlabel').val('spooky');
                $('#file-01').click();

                var filePath = $('#file-01').val().split('\\'),
                    fileName = filePath[filePath.length - 1];

                if (fileName !== '' && fileName !== undefined) {
                    
                    $('.attachmentlabel').val(fileName);
                }
            }

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#file-01").change(function () {
     $('.attachmentlabel').val($(this).val())
});
});
```

```css
.hidden-attachment
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="hidden-attachment" id='file-01'><br>
    <input type="text" name="Attachment" class="attachmentlabel"><br>
     <a  class="btn attachmnentbtn browse" onclick="BrowseFile()">Browse</a>
```

Comment: I dont think this answer is downvoted,+1 from myside

Comment: few minutes back, it was downvoted by someone, anyways thanks for +1

Comment: @MokshShah You are copied my code from `jsFiddle` this is not good.

Comment: @Sadikhasan, man check timings, you posted your comments 10 mins ago, and I answered this question 17 mins ago, dude so just chill, it clearly shows who copied who's answer :D

Comment: @MokshShah My first comment post `24 mins ago` and second comment `12 mins ago` and I recognize my code which you dont know.

Comment: @Sadikhasan, have you lost? your first answer saying `It working fine for me check this jsfiddle.net/q76zfLuq/1` was not at all working and before you ans is 2nd time, I answered it, so please stop crying.

Comment: @Sadikhasan cool dude ,you should have posted fiddle in answer section instead of posting in comments.

Comment: @SpringLearner Do you know why I am telling copied my answer?

Comment: @MokshShah Do you know why I am telling copied my answer?

Comment: @Sadikhasan yes I know,even if he copied then its from your **fiddle** not from your **answer**

Answer (score 0):

```
function BrowseFile() {
      $('#file-01').click();
                $('.attachmentlabel').val('spooky');
                $('#file-01').click();

                var filePath = $('#file-01').val().split('\\');
                    fileName = filePath[filePath.length - 1];

                if (fileName !== '' && fileName !== undefined) {

                    $('.attachmentlabel').val(fileName);
                }
    // Add this code in your function
   $('.hidden-attachment').change(function(){    
         var filename = $(this).val();
         $('.attachmentlabel').val(filename);
     });
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q76zfLuq/5/)**

Comment: What you say @SpringLearner about my answer?